# How to add a 2d plot to a 3d axis drawing?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

My task is quite simple. I want to add to my 3d axis drawing a 2d plot. My closes result is this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            view={45}{30},
            compat=1.8,
            height=10.2cm,
            width=9cm,
            grid=major,
            grid style={dashed, gray!50},
            axis lines=middle,
            inner axis line style={=>},
            yticklabel style={inner ysep=0pt, anchor=south east, font=\tiny},
            ytick={-1,...,1},
            xticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=north west, font=\tiny},
            xtick={-1,...,1},
            zticklabel style={inner ysep=0pt, anchor=south east, font=\tiny},
            ztick={-1,...,1},
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=2,
            zmin=-2,
            zmax=2]
        \addplot+[color=PlotColorOne, samples=30, domain=0:2*pi, thick, smooth, z=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Output]

How is it possible to set z coordinate to 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just treat the required 2d plot as a 3d plot with `z=0`. So using

```
\addplot3 ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},0)`
```

you get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            view={45}{30},
            compat=1.8,
            height=10.2cm,
            width=9cm,
            grid=major,
            grid style={dashed, gray!50},
            axis lines=middle,
            inner axis line style={=>},
            yticklabel style={inner ysep=0pt, anchor=south east, font=\tiny},
            ytick={-1,...,1},
            xticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=north west, font=\tiny},
            xtick={-1,...,1},
            zticklabel style={inner ysep=0pt, anchor=south east, font=\tiny},
            ztick={-1,...,1},
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=2,
            zmin=-2,
            zmax=2]
        \addplot3[color=red, samples=30, domain=0:2*pi, thick, smooth, z=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```